# How to give service reference programatically in wcf?

Tags: wcf

I have a wcf service that present in a different system. I want to add that wcf reference in my production server. But in that server i dont have visual studion. So i cannot go through inbuilt add service reference, can you tell me how i can do this?I want to invoke a wcf service remotely and I dont have visual studio there. I can not go for add service reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
<configuration>  
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RchTransfer.RCHService">
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" address="http://localhost:9000/RCHService"
                    contract="eHeritage.Lib.IRCHService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:9000/RCHService/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>    
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Add IMetadataExchange endpoint to server configuration file

**EDIT**

Otherwise configure WCF service manually

[WCF Services in .Net without using “Add Service Reference”](http://huseyincakir.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/wcf-services-in-net-without-using-%E2%80%9Cadd-service-reference/)

Comment: Hi suppose i have a wcf in 14.1.120.45 and i want to access the wcf in my local system then how i will do that?? i dont have visual studio in my production. only i can add through commandline or something like svcutil

Comment: Visual studio generating code using T4 template. You declare classes manually